# I can't sign into the Django admin login page

Tags: django, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

I have started multiple Django projects with like four different tutorials. Every single time I try "python manage.py createsuperuser", the admin login page just loads and loads and never goes anywhere. I want to make it absolutely clear that I haven't touched a thing in the code and everything is default code. I migrated everything before login. I've tried deleting the database and re-migrating. None of that works. Can someone help me? I have made around 10-15 accounts and NONE of them work. The page just keeps loading indefinitely and never goes anywhere. I've looked at EVERY stackoverflow post and no answers work. I started a virtualenv, downloaded Django, didn't touch the code, made migrations, I followed every tutorial TOO THE LETTER(!!!) and this is what I keep getting. The current tutorial hasn't changed in default code and he signed in with no problems. I'm assuming if he did, I can...I don't think putting code in is necessary since it's all virgin code, never touched. I didn't even make any apps yet.

I've tried deleting database and re-migrating
changing the password of current superuser
deleting the entire project and following everything the instructor said (TO THE LETTER!!!)
I have made 10-15 superuser accounts and none work

Comment: I'm using Django verion 2.2.1 and using this Youtube tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5mRW0jo-U4. Maybe someone could recommend me to a very very recent Django tutorial that won't cause errors if I do everything correctly. I recently asked Udemy for a refund on a tutorial from around April this year. I am so pissed off right now! But I have to get this done because I'm the team leader for my Software Engineering class project.

Comment: I think it's important for me to add that I "saved" one of the username/password accounts on my computer. That may possibly cause problems. I don't know. But it comes up by default every time I go to the "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin" page. Then I erase it and put in the current superuser username/password I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds similar to a problem I was seeing. I wrote a question for it here (no answers yet): [Django local dev server hangs with chrome after form submission. Works in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57814943/django-local-dev-server-hangs-with-chrome-after-form-submission-works-in-firefo?noredirect=1#comment102061174_57814943)

Are you using windows and the chrome browser? Try using firefox to access the admin page and login. That worked for me. I'm still trying to figure out why Chome doesn't work, though. Like you, I created a brand new project from scratch; sometimes Chrome works and most of the time it doesn't. I've also found that hitting the stop button while the browser is sitting there thinking, then refresh, makes the logged in admin page show up.

Comment: Thanks man, you just saved me a ton of aggrivation deleting the sqlite3.db, them make and run migrate, etc. I upvoted your answer, it's right!

Comment: By the way, yes I was using Windows 10 and the Google Chrome browser to sign into the django admin page.

Comment: Really glad this helped you! I was super frustrated for a couple days on this trying to figure out what was going on! Maybe there is a bug in either Django 2.2.4 or Chrome 76.0.3809.132. Or maybe it's something about how Chrome interacts with the virtualenv. Don't know...